# Explain the execution of this sequence: x=j || i++ && 1

Tags: c

I had this question at an interview for C programming. It was:

```
int X,i=4,j=7;
X=j || i++ && 1;
```

What are the values of `X` and `i`?

I tested the program on a compiler, and the output was:

```
X=1 , i =4
```

Can you explain why?

Comment: `||` is a short-circuiting operator. The LHS `j` is "true" therefore the RHS is never evaluated. `i` never gets incremented.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is testing your knowledge of operator precedence (or language grammar if you prefer), and that you know the difference between operator precedence and order-of-evaluation.

The association is:

```
X = (j || (i++ && 1));
```

Note that precedence does not equate to order of execution in general. In this case, we have the following evaluation logic:

- To evaluate `=` we need to evaluate its right-hand operand
- To evaluate `(j || stuff...)` we first evaluate `j`
- `j` is non-zero, so the result of `(j || stuff...)` is `1`, and we do not evaluate `stuff` due to the short-circuit behaviour of `||`
- Now we have determined that the right-hand operand of `=` has evaluated to `1`, so assign `1` to `X`.

Final result: `X == 1`, and `i` and `j` unchanged.

Answer (score 5):

Here only the value of j is checked whether it is true or not,.
If j is true, then the value 1 (true) is assigned to x and then program exits

**note i++ is not executed, 

this is also know as short circuiting in C programming**

```
 int X,i=4,j=7;

 X=j || i++ && 1;

x  = j != 0 // is what is executed
```

If j is 0 only then (i++ && 1) is executed

Comment: If `j == 0` both sides get evaluated, not just `i++ && 1`

Comment: @this I agree with you, but what I mentioned was that the RHS of the expression is evaluated only when j=0,

Answer (score 1):

it reads like this:

```
X = (j != 0 || (i++ != 0 && 1 != 0))
```

In this case, j is "true" (!= 0), so the boolean result of the expression j != 0 is assigned to X.
No need to verify the right hand of the comparaison (i++ != 0 && 1 != 0), as left one already evaluated to true.

i++ is never executed so i retains its original value